# What use cases are there for add-history in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-line

While learning and looking through PowerShell commands, I came across the `add-history` command. It is not clear to me what purpose this command could serve (having already looked through the documentation on the command on [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/add-history?view=powershell-6)), the only plausible reason being that one would want to fabricate history in PowerShell in order to cover their tracks (as the user/a script may have been performing some *shady* business.) **Could someone please give a use-case where the add-history command could be used?**

Comment: Programmatic control over history hardly has to be nefarious. Say you often mistype a command and want to remove the misspelled instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you mentioned reading the docs, but they give several plausible reasons and examples there already (emphasis mine):

> You can use this cmdlet to add specific commands to the history **or to create a single history file that includes commands from more than one session.**

Suppose you have a cluster of machines that are configured identically but you need to run the same commands on them frequently.

You could have a system of sharing history, possibly cherry-picked history, that contains frequently used commands.

Or maybe running a command on any one system is already sufficient to act on all of them, and on any one server you want to be able to see the history of what has been run all the way through (this would show you a single timeline basically of everything run that took effect even if it was executed on another host).

Are there better ways to achieve these things? Yeah almost certainly, but that's little reason not to give the options for someone to manage their history (to say nothing of add-ons, plugins, modules that make the prompt better, etc.).

For example `posh-git`, as a consequence of updating the prompt to show git status must run git commands in the background. Maybe it needs to manipulate history so that those commands don't clog up your command history (no idea if it actually or needs to do this, that might not be the case).

In any case, history is not a security feature. Manipulating it is not a concern.

Comment: Nice, though nothing run from _inside_ a function, including the `prompt` function, shows up in the history.